# The origin is a corner of a square and two of its sides are $y+2x=0$ and $y+2x=3$.

Tags: analytic-geometry

The origin is a corner of a square and two of its sides are $y+2x=0$ and $y+2x=3$. Find the equation of other sides.

My Attempt:
Let $OA$ and $CB$ be the sides of the square $OABC$ with equations $y+2x=0$ and $y+2x=3$.
The equation of line $OC$ perpendicular to $OA$ is 
$$2x-y+k=0$$
Above equation passes through $O(0,0)$. Then
$$2.0-0+k=0$$
$$k=0$$
So, $2x-y=0$ is the required equation.

Comment: This is a bit of a trick question because the equations are given to you with $y$ first. Also, you’re still missing one of the sides.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the equation of line $OC$ wrong. It should be $$2y - x + k = 0$$ This is using the fact that the product of slopes of perpendicular lines is $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since one of the sides lies on $y + 2 x = 0$ which passes though one vertex (the origin), then the other side that passes through this vertex, is the perpendicular line which is

$ -2 y + x = 0$

We also know the third side lies on $y+2x = 3$ , which means the side length which is the distance between the given vertex (the origin) and this line is

$s = \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{5}} $

The fourth side is parallel to $-2 y + x = 0$ and thus lies on the line

$ -2 y + x = c $  where

$ \dfrac{|c|}{ \sqrt{5} } = \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{5}} $

Thus $c $ can be $3$ or $-3$.

Hence the fourth side can lie on $ -2 y + x = 3 $ or $ - 2y + x = -3 $